# How do I fix this code for my image slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been making my website and struggling to make this image slide work. I have been copying it from a youtube video and everything he does seems to work. This is the second time I have tried making one with javascript and the code doesnt seem to work at all.

And yes I have tested my javascript and it was okay. why doesnt my computer process this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Website title </title>

    </head>

    <body>
       <script src = "js/app.js"></script>

    <div class="carousel-container">
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src= "img/img3.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="">
        <img src= "img/img1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src= "img/img2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src= "img/img3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src= "img/img1.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
    <button id="NextBtn">Next</button>


    </body>
</html>

CSS CODE

*{
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.carousel-container{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
.carousel-slide{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

JAVASCRIPT CODE


const  carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');

//Buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

//counter
let counter =1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter)+ 'px)';

//Button listeners
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (counter <= carouselImages.length - 1) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter)+ 'px)';

});

prevBtn.addEventListeners('click', () => {
    if (counter <= 0) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) = 'px)';

});

carouselSlide.addEventListener('tranistionend', ()=>{
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone'){
        carouselSlide.style.transform = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) = 'px)';
    }
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone'){
        carouselSlide.style.transform = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) = 'px)';

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide further information? Like, does it give an error, or does nothing etc.

Comment: it just shows me the pictures side by side and the overflow doesnt even hide the images too. is like some of the javascript code doesnt work, idk im new to this

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mismatch/ errors in the JS code which you can also check in your respective browser console logs

1. In html code the Next button id is '**N**extBtn' but in your js it is referred as 'nextBtn'
2. Instead of `prevBtn.addEventListeners(...)` it should have been `prevBtn.addEventListener(...)` in your app.js code
3. Within the button listener code in JS there are couple of `=` which should have been `+`, for example
   Instead of `carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) = 'px)';` it should have been 
   `carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';`
4. The nextbtn listener logic will always fail i.e counter is initially initialized to 1 and will always be less than the carouselImages.length value which is 5 in this case. 
   Instead of `if (counter <= carouselImages.length - 1) return;` modify it to 
   `if (counter >= carouselImages.length - 1) return;`
5. In styles.css i see the `overflow: hidden;` is commented out. uncomment it and it should work fine
6. You also need to move the script tag in your HTML code to end of the body tag i.e after Next button tag in your case. The reason is the js code tries to calculate the image width (`const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;`) even before the html element have been initialized.

Have a look at your browser console and try to resolve each of the issues.

Comment: Thank u I just solved this before reading your comment! the script tag was the issue.